# Calculating the area of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, area

I need to calculate the area of an ellipse described in polar coordinates by the following equation 
$$r=\frac{p}{1+\epsilon \cos{\theta}},\qquad |\epsilon| < 1$$
I need to so it by solving the following formula
$$A=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_f} \frac{1}{2}r^2\textrm{d}\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\frac{p^2}{(1+\epsilon \cos{\theta})^2}\textrm{d}\theta$$
The problem is that I don't even know where to start with this integral. The problem seems a lot easier if I could transport it to the form
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
without losing the parameters $\epsilon$ and $p$. Never the less, I would still love if somebody could show me a direct integration of this formula! Thanks.

Comment: Contour integration will work.  If you are not familiar with this methodology, then make the substitution $u=\tan(\theta /2)$.

Comment: II think Dr. MV is right. However, do not use the identity explicitly, but playing with this change of variable to get the one that works best for this integral. In general, this is not easy; it takes a little ingenuity.

Comment: I provided a solution using contour integration.  If you are unfamiliar with this methodology, it is a rather powerful one and can sometimes enable the evaluation of integrals that have no simple anti-derivative.  Please let me know how I can improve the answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the $p^2/2$ obviously comes out of the integral, so you are left with doing
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(1+\epsilon \cos{\theta})^2} = 2\int_0^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(1+\epsilon \cos{\theta})^2} $$
since $\cos{(2\pi-\theta)}=\cos{\theta}$.

You could use the $t$-formulae directly, but I'd recommend looking at
$$ I(a)-\int_0^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(a+\cos{\theta})} $$
and then differentiating with respect to $a$: this integral is a lot easier to do. The integral you want is $-I'(1/\epsilon)/\epsilon^2$.

Setting $t = \tan{\tfrac{1}{2}\theta}$, $d\theta = \frac{2 \, dt}{1+t^2}$, and
$$ \cos{\theta} = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, $$
which then gives you
$$ I(a) = 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2 \, dt}{1+t^2} \frac{1+t^2}{(1-t^2)+a(1+t^2)} = 4\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{ (a-1)t^2+(a+1) }, $$
which can be done in the usual way: substitute $t= \sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}} \tan{x}$, which gives the answer
$$ I(a) = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}. $$
Then
$$ -\frac{I'(1/\epsilon)}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{2\pi}{(1-\epsilon^2)^{3/2}} $$

Comment: Thank you! Just a little correction: in I(a) you exchanged the (1-t^2) and the (1+t^2)

Comment: Ah yes, just to check you were paying attention, maybe :). Fix'd.

Answer (score 2):

One may use contour integration to evaluate the integral.  We will start by using the approach that Chappers introduced.  To that end, we write

$$I(\epsilon)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac12 \frac{p^2}{(1+\epsilon \cos \theta)^2}d\theta=\frac{p^2}2 \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(1/\epsilon +\cos \theta)}d\theta$$

Then, we let $z=e^{i\theta}$.  Thus, $\cos \theta =\frac12(z+z^{-1})$ and $d\theta = dz/(iz)$.  This transforms the last integral to a unit-circle contour  integration in the complex z-plane.  Thus

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(1/\epsilon +\cos \theta)}d\theta=-2i\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2+(2/\epsilon)z+1}$$

The integrand has singularities at $z=z_{\pm}=-\frac1{\epsilon}(1 \pm \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2})$.

Inasmuch as $|\epsilon|<1$, the only singularity contained within the unit circle is at $z=z_{-}=-\frac1{\epsilon}(1 - \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2})$.

Thus, the Residue is

$$\frac{1}{(z_{-}-\,z_{+})}=\frac{1}{(-\frac1{\epsilon}(1 - \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}))-(-\frac1{\epsilon}(1 + \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}))}=\frac{\epsilon}{2\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}$$

and the integral $I(\epsilon)$ is

$$I(\epsilon)=\frac{p^2}2 \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\left((-2i)(2\pi i) \frac{\epsilon}{2\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}\right)=\frac{p^2 \pi }{(1-\epsilon)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Thank you! I've never done contour integral a over complex numbers though jajaja

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure to introduce you to this powerful methodology.

Comment: (+1) Good, always nice to see someone thinking before contour integrating! (Although it's not clear that the OP knows the Residue theorem and so on.)

Comment: @Chappers Thanks!  Coming from you, that means a lot.